# How to reveal the choice

Tags: c#

Writing a very simplistic rock paper scissors game.  I need it to reveal the computers choice, so the user knows before they make their choice.  I also need to turn the case sensitivity in the loop off.  Can anyone help me out please?

```
namespace m4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
            Random r = new Random();
            int Player1Choice = r.Next(4);

            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose ");
            string Player1Choice = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Player 2, do you choose rock,paper or scissors");
            string Player2Choice = Console.ReadLine();


            if (Player1Choice == "1")
            {
                if (Player2Choice == "rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Both players chose rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("It is a tie ");
                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose rock, Player 2 chose paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");

                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose rock, Player 2 chose scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins! ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");

                }

            }

            else if (Player1Choice == "2")
            {
                if (Player2Choice == "rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose paper, Player 2 chose rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");

                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Both players chose paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("It is a tie! ");

                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose paper, Player 2 chose scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");
                }
            }
            else if (Player1Choice == "3")
            {
                if (Player2Choice == "rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose scissors, Player 2 chose rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");

                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 chose scissors, Player 2 chose paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");

                }
                else if (Player2Choice == "scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Both players chose scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("It is a tie!");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must choose rock,paper or scissors!");

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");
               }
            } while (Console.ReadLine() == "yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I seem to have figured most of it out, won't know for sure until I can compile it.  Right now I keep getting cs0019 errors on compile for this line of code: while (Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToUpper() == "yes"); its the end of my loop and it needs to be case insensitive, just having issues writing in the proper syntax.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, error was on a different line.  Ok, I have been working on this and it seems I am now getting an error that didn't happen with the original coding.  Since I have taken out the original player 1 and turned them into a computer, my player1choice == lines are now being determined as errors and I have no idea why.

Comment: Damn, fixed that problem.  Got it to compile, the loop and case insensitive are working, the computer chooses it choice and player choose theirs.  However, the computer choice isn't being revealed before player 2 chooses their choice and its not asking if they want to play again

Comment: Another issue solved, another issue arisen.  I have fixed all the issues previous to this comment, but I still haven't figured out how to get it to say the computer chose (rock paper scissors) instead of the the computer chose said integer